# My player ball is shaking when it changes position in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hey guys my question is in the title. Basically when I press play everything is OK, the ball starts to go up without shaking, but when I start swiping to change position it starts shaking.

I already tried different things like changing to `FixedUpdate()` or resetting the player, but it doesn't change. Btw there is no animation on the ball. Can you help me?

Here is the script with the swipe parameters :

```
public class Swipe : MonoBehaviour 
{
private const float DEADZONE = 100.0f;

public static Swipe Instance { set; get; }

private bool tap, swipeLeft, swipeRight, swipeUp, swipeDown;
private Vector2 startTouch, swipeDelta;

public bool Tap { get { return tap; } }
public Vector2 SwipeDelta { get { return swipeDelta; } }
public bool SwipeLeft { get { return swipeLeft; } }
public bool SwipeRight { get { return swipeRight; } }
public bool SwipeUp { get { return swipeUp; } }
public bool SwipeDown { get { return swipeDown; } }

private void Awake()
{
    Instance = this;
}

private void Update()
{
    // Reseting all the booleans
    tap = swipeLeft = swipeRight = swipeDown = swipeUp = false;

    #region Stadalone Inputs
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        tap = true;
        startTouch = Input.mousePosition;
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        startTouch = swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Mobile Inputs
    if (Input.touches.Length != 0)
    {
        if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            tap = true;
            startTouch = Input.mousePosition;
        }
        else if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Ended || Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Canceled)
        {
            startTouch = swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    // Calculate The Distance
    swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
    if (startTouch != Vector2.zero)
    {
        if (Input.touches.Length != 0)
        {
            swipeDelta = Input.touches[0].position - startTouch;
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            swipeDelta = (Vector2)Input.mousePosition - startTouch;
        }
    } 

    // Did we cross the deadzone ?
    if (swipeDelta.magnitude > DEADZONE)
    {
        // Which direction ?
        float x = swipeDelta.x;
        float y = swipeDelta.y;

        if (Mathf.Abs(x) > Mathf.Abs(y))
        {
            // Left or Right
            if (x < 0)
                swipeLeft = true;
            else
                swipeRight = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // Up or Down
            if (y < 0)
                swipeDown = true;
            else
                swipeUp = true;
        }

        startTouch = swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
    }
}   
}
```

And this the part of the script in `Update()` or (`FixedUpdate()`, it doesn't change anything) used to make it move one side or the other on the player :

```
 // Gather the inputs in which tube we should be
    if (Swipe.Instance.SwipeLeft)
        MoveTube(false);
    if (Swipe.Instance.SwipeRight)
        MoveTube(true);


    // Calculate where we should be in the future
    Vector3 targetPosition = transform.position.y * Vector3.up;
    if (desiredTube == 0)
        targetPosition += Vector3.left * TUBE_DISTANCE;
    else if (desiredTube == 2)
        targetPosition += Vector3.right * TUBE_DISTANCE; 

    // Let's calculate our move delta
    Vector3 moveVector = Vector3.zero;
    moveVector.x = (targetPosition - transform.position).normalized.x * speed;
    moveVector.y = speed;

    // Move the ball
    controller.Move(moveVector * Time.deltaTime);

}

private void MoveTube(bool goingRight)
{
    desiredTube += (goingRight) ? 1 : -1;
    desiredTube = Mathf.Clamp(desiredTube, 0, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to solve the problem. So basically I was using the same speed variable to move my ball on the x and y axis and it seems that it created some “switch problem” for unity. So I just created 2 different variables for the speed and I solved the bug like this.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you may be having issue here:

```
// Gather the inputs in which tube we should be
    if (Swipe.Instance.SwipeLeft)
        MoveTube(false);
    if (Swipe.Instance.SwipeRight)
        MoveTube(true);
```

Since `Update()` is invoked once per frame, this means this will be checked several times per second. So it may be changing the position of the player several times per second, giving this shaking effect you mention.

What you could try is to restrict the times the player can swipe per second.

```
private float SwipeRate = 0.1f;
private float NextSwipe = 0.0f;

Update(){

    if (Swipe.Instance.SwipeLeft && Time.time > NextSwipe)
    {
        NextSwipe = Time.time+SwipeRate;
        MoveTube(false);
    }
    if (Swipe.Instance.SwipeRight && Time.time > NextSwipe)
    {
        NextSwipe = Time.time+SwipeRate;
        MoveTube(true);
    }

}
```

**Edit:**

```
private void MoveTube(bool goingRight)
{
    desiredTube += (goingRight) ? 1 : -1;
    desiredTube = Mathf.Clamp(desiredTube, 0, 2);

// Calculate where we should be in the future
    Vector3 targetPosition = transform.position.y * Vector3.up;
    if (desiredTube == 0)
        targetPosition += Vector3.left * TUBE_DISTANCE;
    else if (desiredTube == 2)
        targetPosition += Vector3.right * TUBE_DISTANCE; 

    // Let's calculate our move delta
    Vector3 moveVector = Vector3.zero;
    moveVector.x = (targetPosition - transform.position).normalized.x * speed;
    moveVector.y = speed;

    // Move the ball
    controller.Move(moveVector * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: and he could also try doing it on a `LateUpdate()` ?

Comment: Hi @TheGinxx009 initially I reply that exactly, but I am not sure if just that will solve the problem, since it will keep changing the player position all the time. However it may help as well to reduce the shaking.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try it but can you tell me what is the FireRate variable you used please.

Comment: I just tried it with SwipeRate instead of FireRate but the ball is still shaking.

Comment: @Jake33011 Uff Sorry SwipeRate should be instead of FireRate. I was using this code for something else.

Comment: @Jake33011 Well I just checked and I missed one part, you are still assigning the possition inside the Update, so it will keep reassigning the possition several times per second. Move the last part of the Update into the MoveTube()

Comment: @Ignacio Alorre I did as you told me, I moved first just the last part but then there was a problem with the moveVector variable so I tried to put everything after the call of MoveTube() but the ball didn’t move anymore. So I don’t know if we can fix my problem :(